# hibernate log show update queries, but no select

Tags: hibernate, logging

Is it possible, to set logging in hibernate to show only UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries, but no SELECT? 
I have set my show_sql property to true, but application is spaming my console by a lot of select queries. is it possible to configure it that way?

Im using postgres with Spring and jboss.

I will appreciate any help :)

Comment: You can always filter out all SELECT statements using command line tools i.e: cat server.log | grep -v SELECT

Comment: ok, it's kind of tricky thing, but i would preffer to tell application or jboss to NOT log SELECT statements :)

Comment: No you cannot. It is an all or nothing setting in hibernate. The only possibility would be to create your own filtering appender and filter the SQL from hibernate in there. But it isn't supported out of the box and requires work on your part.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to configure this through log4j.xml of Hibernate logging system, and then apply a Regex to write only the desired log entries.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter